# How to refresh ProgressMonitor in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, progressmonitor

[`ProgressMonitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html) is designed to handle long operations, but if used directly, then it does not refresh.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread worker = new Thread() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      //Code, that's freezing your gui
   }};
worker.start();
```